# is it possible to terminate SSL with Nginx and cache https responses from the backend?

Tags: nginx, ssl, proxy, reverse-proxy, https

Looking to terminate SSL from backend service at nginx and offload to clients as http. Cache all responses for performance and offline scenario. With the setup below I'm not able to cache, what's missing?

```
events {}

http {
    include       mime.types;

    #PROXY
    proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx_cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache_sample:10m max_size=50m;
    proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri:w";
    add_header cache_sample $upstream_cache_status;

    server {
        listen       81;
        server_name  _;

        ssl_verify_client off;

        location ~* {
            proxy_pass https://backend_service;

            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;


            proxy_ssl_certificate           /backend_service.crt;
            proxy_ssl_certificate_key       /backedn_service.key;

            proxy_ssl_ciphers               HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
            proxy_ssl_verify                off;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is stunnel the only option?

Comment: So the flow looks like: `client <HTTP> nginx <HTTPS> proxy`?

Comment: Regarding your problem: You need to introduce [proxy_cache](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache) in your location.

Comment: added [proxy_cache](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache) still failing to cache. From the header `cache_sample → MISS` . As far as the flow, that's correct `client <HTTP> nginx <HTTPS> some_sort_of_service`

Comment: `proxy_ssl_verify                on;` throws a 502, tried with `proxy_ssl_verify_depth          2;` and `proxy_ssl_verify_depth          1;` same result

Comment: So...to sort this out: Besides your cache issue, does the connection to the backend / proxy / some sort of service work? You're speaking about ssl verification now, in your original question you didn't mentioned this. Do you need certs to auth against / at the backend / proxy / some sort of service?

Comment: I have the certs, I was exploring `proxy_ssl_verify` with on and off cases. Not sure if `proxy_ssl_verify` needs to on to support https cache

Comment: Again: Besides the cache issue(s), does the connection to your `some_sort_of_service` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible, try something more like this. I see things missing, and things that look a bit odd, like the ":w" at the end of one line.

This first part goes outside your server block

```
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

# Determines in which cases a stale cached response can be used when an error occurs during
# communication with the FastCGI server
fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;

# Many websites send back inappropriate headers, so ignore them
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;

# Caching. Putting the cache into /dev/shm keeps it in RAM, limited to 10MB, for one day. This is Centos, other distibutions are different.
# You can move to disk if you like, or extend the caching time
fastcgi_cache_path /dev/shm/hr_nginxcache levels=1:2 keys_zone=CACHE_NAME:10m inactive=1440m; #RAM
```

This goes near the top of your server block

```
set $skip_cache 0;
# POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
if ($request_method = POST) {
  set $skip_cache 1;
}
if ($query_string != "") {
  set $skip_cache 1;
}
# Don't cache uris containing the following segments.
# for everyone. I've removed index.php as I want pages cached.
if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
set $skip_cache 1;
}
# Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters
if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in|code") {
  set $skip_cache 1;
}
```

This goes in your location block

```
fastcgi_cache CACHE_NAME;
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 1440m;
add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

fastcgi_cache_methods GET HEAD;
fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
```

You'll have to edit parts to suit your site.

Comment: this is for the php backend; I can try installing `mod_php` on the apache server to validate above. `proxy_cache` would not support above scenario?

Comment: Yes, where I wrote "this goes in your location block" goes inside the location that calls PHP, in my scenario. For you put it in the same location as your proxy_pass. I don't know for sure if it'll work, but there seemed to be fundamental differences in the way you're trying to cache and my working cache so I thought I'd share in the hope that even if my solution isn't quite right it might give you some ideas.

Comment: was missing `fastcgi_cache_valid 200 1440m;` or in my case `proxy_cache_valid 200 1440m;` along with few typos you've covered earlier. Thank you!